# strptime with timestamp and AM/PM

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to convert from string to timestamp using:

```
from datetime import datetime
date_object = datetime.strptime('09-MAR-15 12.54.45.000000000 AM', '%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%f %p')
```

I get:
**ValueError**:

> time data '09-MAR-15 12.54.45.000000000 AM' does not match format
>   '%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%f %p'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below will work as long as the the part after the decimal point always ends in 000. :-) `%f` captures microseconds, while I guess your timestamp uses nanoseconds?

```
date_object = datetime.strptime('09-MAR-15 12.54.45.000000000 AM',
                                '%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%f000 %p')
```

You might consider just chopping off those three digits. E.g.

```
date_object = datetime.strptime(
    re.sub(r'\d{3}( .M)$', r'\1', '09-MAR-15 12.54.45.000000000 AM'),
    '%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%f %p')
```

Comment: yea it's nano-sec. Python can't handle nanosec? :)

Comment: Not `datetime` anyway.